# How to check a model object is persisted to DB or a new object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

```
category = Category.new
```

This isn't persisted to DB yet, so how to distinguish form an object that is saved in the database?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
c.persisted?  # => true if persisted
c.new_record? # => true if not persisted
```

:)

Comment: worth mentioning that `persisted?` isn't defined until Rails 3.0 http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/persisted%3F

Answer (score 3):

```
c.new_record? # true if new, false if saved
```